# fetch equal number of rows for the given categories

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL table design is:

```
id, 
name,
department,
status,
value
```

The ask is to fetch equal number of records from each department. Maximum number of rows allowed per fetch is restricted to 100 rows. Assume that there are 4 distinct departments (A,B,C and D) in the table. For each department there are few hundred records. So, the query should fetch only 25 records for each department. And if the distinct department size is three than the split should be 100/3.

I used the below query. But it is not calculating the number of rows for each department dynamically. Currently I have used 25 a constant value.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT dept.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY dept.department
                            ORDER BY dept.department, dept.id ) deptEntry
  FROM   TABLE_NAME dept
) dept
WHERE dept.deptEntry <=25
AND   dept.status='ACTIVE'
AND   rownum <=100;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort MTO. I missed one more scenario to include. I am not sure if this is possible in a single query execution. There could few departments may have only lesser number of rows. For ex: department 'A' can have 40 records. Department 'B' can have only 3 records. 'C' and 'D' can have 300 records each. In this case, the outcome of the query execution returns 25 records from 'A', 3 from 'B', 25 records from 'C' and 'D'. So the total number of records fetched are 78. Is there a dynamic way of approach to split the remaining 22 records between the other 3 departments?

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of distinct departments and then divide your number of rows by that value:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT dept.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY department
                            ORDER BY department, id ) AS deptEntry,
         COUNT( DISTINCT department ) OVER () AS num_dept
  FROM   TABLE_NAME dept
) dept
WHERE dept.deptEntry <= 100 / num_dept
AND   dept.status='ACTIVE'
AND   rownum <=100;
```

**Updated**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT dept.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY department
                            ORDER BY id ) AS deptEntry
  FROM   TABLE_NAME dept
  WHERE  status = 'ACTIVE'
  ORDER BY deptEntry, department
) dept
WHERE ROWNUM <=100;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I missed one more scenario to include. I am not sure if this is possible in a single query execution. There could few departments may have only lesser number of rows. For ex: department 'A' can have 40 records. Department 'B' can have only 3 records. 'C' and 'D' can have 300 records each. In this case, the outcome of the query execution returns

Comment: Wow!! It worked. Thanks a lot :) I am wondering how did this manage to dynamically add/remove the rows just by removing the deptEntry <=100 entry.

Comment: @Ram You also need to add `ORDER BY` to the inner query. The `ORDER BY` enforces that it will get one from each department in turn.

Comment: Yes I added it. Thank you!!